# What is a proper naming convention for related tables and models in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have two user types in my application: **Investors** and **Advisors**, they both have a separate model and table in database (Investor model, Advisor model, Investors table and Advisors table).

I need to create a table to keep advisor's profile data and a different table to keep investor's profile(they have completely different fields in profile, so i cant merge into a single table). What name should i give to it? If i call it investor_profile - then every time i want to get a data from it i have to call it `investor->investor_profile->field_name` but thats seems bad to type investor twice.

Any advises for a proper name? Or maybe a trick to make it `investor->profile->field_name`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might store different tables for `investor_profiles` and `advisor_profiles` with separate models `InvestorProfile, AdvisorProfile` (which both might inherit from a base `Profile` class, assuming they have at least a tiny bit of overlap).

But in your model associations, use the `:class_name` option to hide the `_profiles`:

```
class Investor < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_one :profile, :class_name => "InvestorProfile" 
end


class Advisor < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_one :profile, :class_name => "AdvisorProfile" 
end

# And since the profiles probably overlap in some way
# a profile base class which the other 2 profile classes extend
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  # base options like name, address, etc...
end  
class InvestorProfile < Profile
  # Investor-specific stuff
end
class AdvisorProfile < Profile
  # Advisor-specific stuff
end
```

In practice then, you can refer to it as `self.profile`:

```
# Use it as
adv = Advisor.new
puts adv.profile.inspect
```

See the [`ActiveRecord::Associations` documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many) for descriptions of the options.

Comment: Thanks @Michael, very good answer, other answers are good too, but yours is the most informative.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it makes sense to have **investor_profile** and **advisor_profile** if they are different and therefore you can't use the same model.

Don't worry about accessing and repeating names, because you can do this:

```
class Investor
     has_one :profile, class_name: "InvestorProfile"
end
```

And given an Investor object, you will be able to do stuff like `@investor.profile.profile_field`

Answer (score 1):

You [can name the association as you want](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_one-class_name) and specify the name of the model class:

```
class InvestorProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Investor_profiles table must contain an investor_id column
  belongs_to :investor
end

class Investor < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Thanks to the :class_name option rails know what a profile is
  has_one :profile, :class_name => "InvestorProfile"
end
```

and then you can access the profile fields using something like this `@investor.profile.field_name`.